# Wordpress multisite URL rewrite htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite, domain-mapping

I am running wordpress multisite on a server. The main site is working just fine are url redirects are perfect. 
Say my domain is `www.adeel.com` and the site is run on following url `www.adeel.com/area-guides`. Because at `www.adeel.com` another site is running(not in wordpress, completely different).

**The issue**

From admin panel when I try to go to network admin dashboard it redirects me to 
`www.adeel.com/wp-admin/network/` and it displays URL NOT FOUND. If i type in manually `www.adeel.com/area-guides/wp-admin/network/`, it takes me to the network dashboard. And inside that dashboard all url starts from `area-guides` except when I try do something that updates that page.

Below is my htaccess file rules

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

 # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

and content of wp-config file are as follow

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.adeel.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

And in the wp_options table for main site.
- site url: `https://www.adeel.com/area-guides/`
- home: `https://www.adeel.com/area-guides/`

**2nd questions**
Once this is solved, for another multisite I'd like to add the site at same level e.g www.adeel.com/another-guide/